# Multi-Screen Setting

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an images of size (width = 1444 * height = 760). Now i want to show it in imageview to set imageview weight and height i create different file for dimens.xml like:

dimens.xml
dimens.xml(hdpi)
dimens.xml(mdpi)
 
dimens.xml(xhdpi)
dimens.xml(xxhdpi)
dimens.xml(xxxhdpi)
dimens.xml(sw600dpi)
dimens.xml(sw720hdpi)

Now to set the image-view height and width. what size value to put in which dimens.xml file please help and sorry for English mistakes if any...

Comment: see this: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

LDPI: Portrait: 200 X 320px

MDPI: Portrait: 320 X 480px

HDPI: Portrait: 480 X 800px

XHDPI: Portrait: 720 X 1280px

XXHDPI: Portrait: 960 X 1600px

XXXHDPI: Portrait: 1440 x 2560px

Comment: i think its screen size what shoud be the size (width and height) of image view if layout contains three items

Comment: @BilalAminKhan Depends on you , how big do you want it to be ? you can make it `<ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size" />`